# Как в php через strpos (stripos) найти позицию вхождение любой кириллической буквы?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как с помощью функции **strpos** (**stripos**) найти позицию вхождение любой кириллической буквы? Если есть конкретная фраза - то проблем нет. НО вот как быть, если не знаю, какая ПЕРВАЯ буква из русского алфавита может быть в строке (строка практически вся на english)?

Comment: для многобайтовых кодировок вроде бы есть `mb_strpos()`.

Answer (score 1):

Честно, не совсем понял суть вопроса, но если вопрос состоит в том, чтобы найти первый символ из кириллицы, то можно так:

```
$string = 'qwerty Привет qerty';
preg_match('/[а-я]/iu', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Результат будет такой:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => string(2) "П"
  [1] => int(7)
}
```

В массиве собсна первый символ и его позиция.

---

Через `strpos`, а точнее `mb_stripos`:

```
function mb_stripos_array($haystack, $needles = array(), $offset = 0)
{
    $chr = array();
    foreach ($needles as $needle)
    {
        $res = mb_stripos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
        if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle]   = $res;
    }
    if (empty($chr)) return false;
    return min($chr);
}

$range = [];
for ($i = 224; $i <= 255; $i++) {
  $range[] = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', chr($i));
}



$string = 'qwerty Привет qerty';
var_dump(mb_stripos_array($string, $range));
```

`mb_stripos_array` результат аналогичен результату `mb_stripos`. Т.е. вернет первое вхождение, но если-же еще надо знать какой символ, то:

```
return min($chr);
```

Заменяем на:

```
$value = min($chr);
return [mb_substr($haystack, $value, 1), $value];
```

Comment: Manitikyl, а не подскажите, возможно имеется решение данного вопроса средствами strpos, а не регуляркой?

Comment: @НиколайАгеев я добавил в свой ответ мой вариант через `strpos`, но это дикий костыль, не знаю даже зачем вам такое надо...